# laravel 5.7 how to update datetime field to null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

■ Laravel : 5.7

■ PHP : 7.2

I need to update model *DateTime* Field to null, but I don't know why when I input to null will update Field to current date time.

When I set form `job_start` or `job_end` on blank, than will update Field to current date time.

Also, I already have try `$job->job_start = null; $job->save();` but get same result.

```
 class Job extends Model {

     /**
     * @var $casts（toArray、toJson）
     */
     protected $casts = [
        'visit_date' => 'date:Y-m-d',
        'job_start' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i',
        'job_end' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i',
     ];

     /**
      * @var date 
     */
     protected $dates = [
        'visit_date', 
        'job_start',
        'job_end',
     ];

     // $fillable（save、update、fill）
     protected $fillable = [
        /**SKIP**/
        'visit_date', 
        'job_start',
        'job_end',
        /**SKIP**/
     ];

     /**SKIP other function**/

     /**
      *　job_start
      * @param  string  $value ($value format 'Y:m:d H:i')
      * @return void
      */
     public function setJobStartAttribute($value) {
        if($value !== null){
            //$value format 'Y:m:d H:i' to 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
            $value = (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        //set
        $this->attributes['job_start'] = $value;
     }

     /**
      *　job_start
      * @param  string  $value ($value format 'Y:m:d H:i:s')
      * @return void
      */
     public function getJobStartAttribute($value) {
        //$value format 'Y:m:d H:i:s' to 'Y-m-d H:i'
        return (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
     }
 }
```

Relate migration setting :

```
Schema::create('jobs', function(Blueprint $table) {
  /**Relate Migration setting**/
  $table->dateTime('job_start')->nullable();
  $table->dateTime('job_end')->nullable();
});
```

Already try :

```
public function update($id, Request $request) {
  $job = Job::findOrFail($id);
  $job->fill( $request->input() );
  //test set job_start null as below,
  //but I don't know why when I input to null will update Field to current date time.
  $job->job_start = null;
  $job->save();
}
```

Comment: Does your datetime is nullable?

Comment: `'job_start' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i',` will cast a null to '1970-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: Check your migration, Maybe it has defined a default value.

Comment: Schema::create('jobs', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
        /**Relate Migration setting**/
        $table->dateTime('job_start')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('job_end')->nullable();
        });

Comment: The `setJobStartAttribute` method probably should not be there if you dont want the current date to be set

Comment: You are using 3 cast options in parallel, but you should only use one. Best you remove the datetime columns from `$casts` and also remove the custom mutator/accessor. If you want a custom accessor with a special format, I suggest using a getter function. Overriding the property defaults is not the best idea in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for getting back the current day is that:

When your property assessor does its thing for a `null` value it evaluates to `new Carbon(null)` which is equivalent to `Carbon::now()`

```php
public function getJobStartAttribute($value) {
        //$value format 'Y:m:d H:i:s' to 'Y-m-d H:i'
    return (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
```

You can fix that path by writing

```php
public function getJobStartAttribute($value) {
    if ($value !== null) {
        //$value format 'Y:m:d H:i:s' to 'Y-m-d H:i'
       return (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Also, remove `jobStart` from `$casts` attributes. Otherwise, you get the same behaviour with `null` values of `jobStart` casted to current date.

One more reason to remove it is that the assessor already formats the date.